# Thread BLOCKED on org.apache.log4j.Category.callAppenders, but not waiting for any lock

Tags: java, multithreading, log4j

My web application(delpoyed on weblogic) went down, when I check the jstack info, I found most threads are BLOCKED on a org.apache.log4j.spi.RootLogger. The thread owning this lock is also BLOCKED and stucked for at least 20min until i kill the process, but it's not waiting on any other lock, how does this happen?

here is the jstack info:

the BLOCKED thread owning lock <783b8910>, but not waiting on other locks:

```
"[STUCK] ExecuteThread: '58' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'" daemon prio=7 tid=02e45400 nid=86 lwp_id=7959740 waiting for monitor entry [61cff000]
java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
at org.apache.log4j.Category.callAppenders(Category.java:201)
- locked <783b8910> (a org.apache.log4j.spi.RootLogger)
at org.apache.log4j.Category.forcedLog(Category.java:388)
at org.apache.log4j.Category.error(Category.java:302)
```

other threads waiting to lock <783b8910>:

```
"[STUCK] ExecuteThread: '36' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'" daemon prio=7 tid=02e0ea00 nid=64 lwp_id=7959717 waiting for monitor entry [62d7f000]
java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
at org.apache.log4j.Category.callAppenders(Category.java:201)
- waiting to lock <783b8910> (a org.apache.log4j.spi.RootLogger)
at org.apache.log4j.Category.forcedLog(Category.java:388)
at org.apache.log4j.Category.error(Category.java:319)
```

and

```
"[STUCK] ExecuteThread: '34' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'" daemon prio=7 tid=02e0a200 nid=62 lwp_id=7959715 waiting for monitor entry [62eff000]
java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
at org.apache.log4j.Category.callAppenders(Category.java:201)
- waiting to lock <783b8910> (a org.apache.log4j.spi.RootLogger)
at org.apache.log4j.Category.forcedLog(Category.java:388)
at org.apache.log4j.Category.info(Category.java:663)
```

and so on, total 64 threads are waiting to lock <783b8910>

this happens about 1-3 times a month, I cannot find a solution because I don't know why the thread owning the lock is BLOCKED while not waiting for other locks.

the log4j version is 1.2.13

Comment: who owned lock on <783b8910> ?

Comment: Who is owning <61cff000> and how long it's blocked for this thread?

Comment: no one is owning 61cff000, at least i cannot find in jstack ouput. the thread is blocked for at least 20min

Comment: My suspicion would be that the actual file-write call got stuck for some reason, such as a hung NFS mount.

Comment: look for slow filer? filer space? file descriptor count?

Comment: I'd just like to point out that Log4j 1.2.13 was released in 2005 and was essentially "replaced" by the same author, due to inherent flaws in the log4j design, in the form of slf4j and logback, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log4j

Answer (score 0):

On Java Command Windows, if you have clicked to stop printing logs then this thread blocking occurs at printing logs, so thread goes on Blocked state while printing logs.

So if this is the issue you can use AsyncAppender.

Answer (score 0):

> ... total 64 threads are waiting to lock <783b8910>

The threads are all trying to write log4j messages in `Category.callAppenders(LoggingEvent event)`.  You should download the log4j source and then specifically look at the code lines corresponding to your thread stacktrace lines.  The lines around there are:

```
for(Category c = this; c != null; c=c.parent) {
  // Protected against simultaneous call to addAppender, removeAppender,...
  synchronized(c) {
     if(c.aai != null) {
        writes += c.aai.appendLoopOnAppenders(event);
```

I susepct that one of the threads is actually holding the lock.  If you carefully look at all of the thread stacktraces, some other thread's stack is in `org.apache.log4j.Category` but is not blocked at line 201.  Maybe it is calling `org.apache.log4j.helpers.AppenderAttachableImpl.appendLoopOnAppenders(LoggingEvent)` which is blocking for some reason.

Take a look at the actual appender implementation in question.  Any chance it is writing to a network drive that is offline or something?

**WARNING:** Now in 2024, log4j version 1 has [significant security holes](https://www.trendmicro.com/en_us/what-is/apache-log4j-vulnerability.html) in it.  You should find and fix the problem your locking issue with your code but afterwards you should consider upgrading to log4j v2.

Comment: This question predates the EOL announcement of Log4j 1.x. Log4j 1.x had also known locking issues that required an architecture change.

Comment: You are correct @PiotrP.Karwasz.  No idea why it showed this message to me to answer.  I've edited my warning.  Thanks.